# How to solve encoding issue while getting a page's source code?

Tags: c#, html, .net, html-agility-pack

I was getting page source code with

```
          Uri url = new Uri(urlAddress);
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        string htlm = client.DownloadString(url);
```

but it gives character issue at kickass.to (torrrent site) even though it writes

```
     "meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8""
```

at the source code.

also tried this method http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1954/get_web_page_contents_in_code_with_csharp/ to get source code which didnt work

example  source code:  http://pastebin.com/ycBjWLRi

How can I get source code properly?

Comment: "character issue" what problem do you have exactly?

Comment: @VladimirGondarev I get "�\b\0\0\0\0\0\0�}ys�F�����r�+{i�8\b�%�x��w}���$?�....." when I try to get page source code. is this something with javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed something about forcing character encoding in a recent article I read over at:

- [Html Agility Pack - Massive Information Extraction](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/691119/Html-Agility-Pack-Massive-information-extraction-f)

It says you should set it up like this:

```
HtmlWeb htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb() { 
  AutoDetectEncoding = false, 
  OverrideEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-2") 
};
```

This is using Html Agility Pack which you have tagged your question with but you dont seem to have actually used it in your code example above or in the article you linked out to on tech-recipes.com.

Comment: I couldnt make this work http://i.imgur.com/luIX0Nw.png  it gives "Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid"  but I found this http://i.imgur.com/NhKnZYU.png which works as I wanted. how can I implement yours?